# App Crashes when not connected to Xcode iOS 9(beta 2)?

Tags: ios9, xcode7-beta2

I have installed my app on iOS9 Beta 2 and It doesn't crash when it was run through xcode, as soon as I detach device from the xcode it starts crashing. Below is the crash log, got from the xcode console:

TCP Conn 0x1566cf10 released
Jul  3 14:43:26 iPhone-5 assertiond[60] : Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 382: (os/kern) failure (5)
Jul  3 14:43:26 iPhone-5 SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[44] : Unable to register for exec notifications: No such process
Jul  3 14:43:26 iPhone-5 SpringBoard(BaseBoard)[44] : Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 382: (os/kern) failure (5)
Jul  3 14:43:26 iPhone-5 SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[44] : Unable to obtain a task name port right for ; pid: 382>
Jul  3 14:43:26 iPhone-5 SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[44] : Application '{contents = “UIKitApplication:[0x9dc3]"}'

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.....

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the DeploymentTarget to iOS 7.0 and above.

**OR**

I was also facing the same issue. In my case the crash log was containing the following error message:

Dyld Message: no cache image with name (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore)

```
Incident Identifier: E37B25ED-0D52-4AA6-9418-96D3EEF56730
CrashReporter Key:   92c611b757eff682f584794eea6ed79651a5307f
Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
Process:             XXXX [378]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/10AD5592-F872-46AA-9B8A-5BD437BC3437/XXXX.app/XXXX
Identifier:          XXXXXXXXXX
Version:             4.7 (4.5)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-07-07 18:17:35.35 +0530
Launch Time:         2015-07-07 18:17:35.35 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 9.0 (13A4280e)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: no cache image with name (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore)
  Dyld Version: 366.5

Binary Images:
0x45000 - 0x134fff XXXXX armv7  <e9dea1918cc63374aace690ca7079049> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/10AD5592-F872-46AA-9B8A-5BD437BC3437/XXXX.app/XXXX
0x1fe47000 - 0x1fe6efff dyld armv7  <37ecf6928e2d34c89b64eaa2e694c55a> /usr/lib/dyld

Error Formulating Crash Report:
Failed while requesting activity/breadcrumb diagnostics
```

So in my case the XCDYoutubeKit was using the javascript.framework. So to solve the crash temporarily I removed the XCDYoutubeKit library from my project which has solved the crash issue in my app.You can try the same solution.

For fix: Please refer below link
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/ios9/